# vertical space after \hrulefill

Tags: formatting, vertical-alignment

I use the following as a title for my draft document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Various packages

\begin{document}

%%% Title
\begin{center}

\hrulefill\\
\textit{\bfseries \Huge The name of my draft}\\ 
\hrulefill 

\begin{flushright}
\textit{my name}
\end{flushright}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

The code generates a vertical space between the last `\hrule` and `my name`.

How can I decrease that space?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some lower level commands in this case seem to give a better and easier to reach result:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Various packages

\begin{document}

%%% Title
{\centering

\hrule
\kern3pt

{\Huge\itshape\bfseries \Huge The name of my draft}

\kern3pt
\hrule
\kern9pt
}
{\raggedleft\itshape my name\par}

\vspace{1cm}

The text starts here

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can act on the dimensions after `\kern` to tune up the spacing.

Comment: that actually looks nicer :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `\raggedleft` instead of the `flushright` environment.

Remove the `\\` after `\hrulefill` and as well after `\textit{...}` command also and leave an empty line instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

% Various packages

\begin{document}

%%% Title
\begin{center}

\hrulefill

\textit{\bfseries \Huge The name of my draft}

\hrulefill 

\raggedleft\textit{my name}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]